# Program with MPI_Reduce "hangs" after executing

Tags: c++, mpi

I want to write a C++ program that counts the sum of elements on each position of multiple arrays. Arrays are generated in every process. I've implemented it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "mpi.h"

int ROOT = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int procNum, procRank;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procNum);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procRank);

    int N = procNum + 5;
    int* a = new int[N];

    srand(procRank);
    std::cout << "Process #" << procRank << " generated array:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    int* sendbuf = new int [N];
    int* recvbuf = new int [N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        sendbuf[i] = a[i];

    MPI_Reduce(sendbuf, recvbuf, N, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (procRank == 0) {
        std::cout << "Process #0 received sums:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            std::cout << "Sum #" << i << ": " << recvbuf[i] << "\t";
        }
    }

    delete[] a;
    delete[] recvbuf;
    delete[] sendbuf;

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

It seems to work fine except for one thing: it almost never finishes properly. I can only stop it by pressing ctrl+c. Looks like the program is waiting for a random process to do something but the process does nothing. What should I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you wnt to write C++, get rid of the `new` stuff. Then start using the `<random>` random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return 0;` at the end. Using g++ and OpenMPI on linux I was unable to reproduce your problem (i.e. the program terminated correctly with the correct output), but maybe on your system/implementation it is necessary for the main function to return properly.